# Alternate to nested FOR Loop

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was looking an old project and i saw one code there that I am explaning here:

The code was loading some records(domain objects) from database then iterate over it then for each iteration they are getting on object through which they are loading again a list. They are doing this activity by putting nested for-loops in the code.

```
ParentList = getFromDatabse;
for(....){ // over ParentList
     SubChild1List = fromParentObejct;
     for(... ) { // over SubChild1List 
       subChild2List = fromSubChild1Objectl
        .. so on
```

The code is having 7 nested loops.

My question is to suggest me some good design-pattern to avoid such a messy code.

Comment: Which language, language version, platform, etc?

Comment: I m sorry for not specifying Language. We are using Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the visitor pattern and recursion. It's hard to say more since your code does not tell much.

Comment: Thanks! I suggested the same to use Visitor pattern. I just want to confirm from the experts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to optimize the way you are getting data from database. Maybe then you won't need do processing by nesting for loops again n again (Pls provide more details).